# 2 x 4 in the way of Drywall - Existing home

Tags: drywall, drywall-anchor

I am attempting to drywall under my stairs, but do not have a flush option. I have a 2 x 4 that is creating a lip about 1/4" all the way down one wall, is it possible to drywall this area too? I'm a seasoned home repair person, but have not encountered this before. Usually everything is plum, and not creating additional problems! Here's my photo for reference. [image: Naked Boards, waiting for drywall]

Comment: It might be there to keep drywall off a floor that might get damp/wet.

Comment: a baseboard would cover that

Comment: @jsotola  If OP means a 1/4 inch lip left after drywall, then mitring baseboard corners gets interesting.

Comment: If you're talking about the piece of wood on the floor, the easy button is to place some other vertical members flush with its face, then fasten the drywall to those.

Answer (score 1):

If that is just 1/4 inch then the quickest and easiest way to drywall is to put up a 1/4" sheet and then the 1/2" over it.

Comment: That or fur it out.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest thing to do is fur it out. Add 2x4s/ 2x2s to make a nice square surface to drywall. (Or if you don't mind losing the space, add another wall on the inside of the current one).

Speaking from experience anything else will be really labor intensive and end up pretty ugly.